# Subequation is adding a random 9 to the end of my equation

Tags: equations, subequations

Here is the full equation block:

```
    \documentclass[12pt, English]{article}
    \usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb}
    \usepackage{epsf, subfigure, verbatim, epsfig}
    \usepackage{lineno, color}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{verbose,letterpaper,tmargin=2.54cm,bmargin=2.54cm,
    lmargin=2.54cm,rmargin=2.54cm}  
    \newtheorem{defi}{Definition}
    \newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
    \newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}
    \newtheorem{lemm}{Lemma}
    \newtheorem{rema}{Remark}
    \newtheorem{coro}{Corollary}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{Tr}
    \newcommand{\dsize}{\displaystyle}
    \newcommand{\jdn}{\textcolor{blue}}
    \newcommand{\njr}{\textcolor{red}}
    \newcommand{\am}{\textcolor{NavyBlue}}
    \newcommand{\dif}{\mathrm{d}}
    \linenumbers
    %\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{p}{,}{,}
    % Patch to fix line numbering problem
    \newcommand*\patchAmsMathEnvironmentForLineno[1]{%
        \expandafter\let\csname old#1\expandafter\endcsname
        \csname #1\endcsname
        \expandafter\let\csname oldend#1\expandafter\endcsname
        \csnameend#1\endcsname
        \renewenvironment{#1}%
        {\linenomath\csname old#1\endcsname}%
        {\csname oldend#1\endcsname\endlinenomath}}% 
    \newcommand*\patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno[1]{%
        \patchAmsMathEnvironmentForLineno{#1}%
        \patchAmsMathEnvironmentForLineno{#1*}}%
    \AtBeginDocument{%
        \patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{equation}%
        \patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{align}%
        \patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{flalign}%
        \patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{alignat}%
        \patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{gather}%
        \patchBothAmsMathEnvironmentsForLineno{multline}%
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
Title
\end{titlepage}
\begin{abstract}
Abstract
\end{abstract}
\section{Model}

\begin{subequations} \label{eq:MainMod}
\begin{align}
x_1(n+1) &= \lambda_s x_1(n) + (1-\delta_m)\lambda_m x_2(n) + (1-    
\delta_h)\lambda_h x_3(n) + \eta_s \lambda_c x_4(n)\\ 
& \hspace{5ex} + (1-\mu_s)\hat{x}_1(n,1) + \alpha_m (1-\mu_m) 
\hat{x}_2(n,1), \nonumber\\ 
x_2(n+1) &= \eta_m \lambda_c x_4(n) + (1-\mu_m)(1-\alpha_m)\hat{x}_2(n,1),\\
x_3(n+1) &= \delta_h \lambda_h x_3(n) + \eta_h \lambda_c x_4(n) + (1-
\mu_h)\hat{x}_3(n,1) + \alpha_c (1-\mu_c) \hat{x}_4(n,1),\\
x_4(n+1) &= (1-\mu_c) (1-\alpha_c) \hat{x}_4(n,1),
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

And it shows up normally until the last line which looks like:

x_4(n+1) = (1-mu_c)(1-alpha_c)xhat_4(n,1),^9

(Can I attach a screenshot somehow?)

I've tried eliminating the comma right after the last term in the code, but that doesn't work.

Comment: please merge your two code snippets to one small but complete document which reproduce your problem. in this please remove all not relevant stuff from document preamble. help us to help you! welcome to tex.se!

Comment: @Zarko I'm slightly new to latex, so I was hoping  to provide full disclosure of my preamble in case there was something I wasn't aware of :\

Comment: @Zarko  I deleted a few, but really not sure about the others.

Comment: well, delete wsome preamble and test, if your problem still presis. do thes so far, that you cancompile your equation. i test it and in `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{amsmath}\begin{document}.... your equations...\end{document}` i can't reproduce your proble.

Comment: even with your document i cant reproduce your problem. do you test this code? does it still reproduce your problem?                    
    do you really need line numbering and all this patch for it? i cant see any benefits of them.

Comment: @Zarko I actually can't reproduce the problem either in another document with the full preamble. Which is more confusing than anything. Before, I've been able to solve tex problems by literally re-typing the bad section. I don't know why that's worked before, but I may try it here. So on that note, do you have any idea why re-typing things changes stuff?

Comment: difficult to say. it seems that you have in text hidden character not visible in editor.in this particular case only last few letter of equation. but this is not a solution. you probably has some mismatch font coding settings. i'm not expert for this.

Comment: @Zarko I've finally realized that the 9 is actually the page number at the bottom of the page, but the equation is overflowing into the bottom margin. I've tried adding `\sloppy` after `\begin{document}` but that hasn't seemed to help.

Comment: try to add `\allowdisplaybreaks` in your document preamble. it may help.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks man. It's not working yet, but I'll just hope that it doesn't fall into the margin once the paper is finished haha. I really appreciate your help all day though. Thanks so much.